# Android Bluetooth OutputStream slow write

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, inputstream

I'm building a client-server android application. One app is installed in Google Glass and sends video frames captured by the camera and sent via Bluetooth connection. Another application is installed in an Android device and reads the video frames. When reading from the stream `len = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);` it seems like the maximum byte count read is 990. It doesn't matter if I set bufferSize to an extremely large number.

- I'm sending a 320x240 image frame with 4 channels. So this is a total
  of 307200 bytes. So when reading the entire image, it is being read
  in chunks of 990 bytes which I think affects the speed of my app. It
  takes 1-3 seconds to read all data. Is there a way to change the
  maximum bytes read? Is this an application setting or controlled by
  the Android OS? I'm not sure if reading all data at once would affect
  performance but I am just curious.

UPDATE:
I notice the same thing when sending the data from Google Glass using OutputStream. It takes about 2 seconds to write to the OutputStream. Is this normal performance for Bluetooth connection? Is there a better way to transmit camera capture frames between 2 devices?

UPDATE 2:
I think the delay is in the write speed. Writing the data to the stream takes about 2 seconds. When the other app is trying to read the data, it probably waits for the complete data to be written to the stream. Still not sure if this is as expected or can still be improved.

Comment: Increase the socket receive buffer size, if you can with a Bluetooh socket.

Comment: @EJP I did a quick search on this but I couldn't find any information about changing the receive buffer size.

Comment: Did you call `flush` on write stream ?

Comment: @mr.icetea not sure how that affects it. But I tried adding flush after writing the data and it's still the same.

Comment: did you get any solution? i am also facing same issue . Sometime write taking too much time i.e 2-3 seconds